# SSRS report collapsing and expanding part of the table

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2017

I have a table of many columns:

[Column names/table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQ4Zs.png)

Is there a way to make collapse/expand feature to the table part "Product Shelf Life History"?
Because the tablix is too big, the user has to scroll all the way to the right side. That part is not important and should be hidden if not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a parameter to the report and correlate it to the visibility of those columns.

For example:

- Create a parameter (Boolean) and set the default to false.
- Right click the column and go to Column Visibility.
- Select Show or Hide based on an expression.
- Create an expression, `=IIF(parameter == True, True, False)`

It doesn't have to be a Boolean, it is just an example. You can also use a dropdown with the two options or you can even add more.